# issues with ldap query for users from a trusted domain

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I have some issues with a ldap query for users from a trusted domain:

I have two completely independent domains:

```
DomainA (dc=mycity, dc=mycompany, dc=local)
```

and

```
DomainB (dc=test, dc=somewhat, dc=local).
```

`DomainB` trusts `DomainA` (one way).
Both domains were setup and are controlled by customers.

`DomainA` has a global group `„fs“` and some users (for example user1 and user2, both members of DomainA) are member of this group.

`DomainB` has a local group `„companyusers“` and `fs` is added as a member.
This local group is a member of another group (for exaple `„admins“` or `„servicedesk“`).

Now when I query `DomainB` and filter is set with `(sMAAccountname = user1)` I don't get any results. Also when I query all members with

```
(memberof=CN=companyusers,CN=users,dc=test,dc=somewhat,dc=local)
```

or

```
(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=companyusers,CN=users,dc=test,dc=somewhat,de=local)
```

I still can't see the users which are part of DomainA.

> ["CN=companyusers,CN=users,dc=test,dc=somewhat,de=local"

is the path when I do the query with

```
(&(objectClass=group)(name=companyusers))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept to be able to perform a LDAP Query across AD Domains is complex and has several dependencies.

To perform a LDAP Query across domains **MUST** be in the same AD Forrest and you would need to connect to the [Global Catalog](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Global%20Catalog).

You can locate the Distinguished names of Domain Controllers which host the Global Catalog using the following LDAP Query:

```
(&(objectClass=nTDSDSA)(options:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=1))
```

Even then LDAP Query will only work group members unless all [Group Types](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20Groups) are Universal Groups.

Finally, [1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941) (LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN) filters ONLY work against Distinguished name based attributes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer :) So in my case it is not possible, because there are two AD forrests

Comment: Is there a Trust between them?

Comment: Yes, DomainB trusts DomainA, but only one way. I query against DomainB but the users are setup in DomainA.

Comment: To locate the GC servers, it seems to be mandatory to use the *Configuration* container as the searchbase, e. g. `LDAP://CN=Configuration,DC=contoso,DC=com`.

Comment: I'd love to see an example on how to craft an LDAP query (search-root/base and filter) that asks a GC of DomainA to return objects of DomainB (given there is a bidirectional trust between both domains).

Comment: Global Catalog provides a searchable catalog of all objects in every AD DOMAIN in an AD Forest.
So if DomainA and DomainB are in the same AD Forest, all DCs are in the Global Catalog. 
The AD Forest is the "Security Realm" for Microsoft Active Directory.
If they are not in the same AD Forest, then you would need to use Forest Trust or Implementing a UIdP like Azure Active Directory (AD) or replicate relevant information from DomainB to DomainA (Not recommended)